# Marginal probability of C with respect to A?

Tags: probability, marginal-distribution

I red the following statement in a book:

"Marginal probability  of C with respect to A" - but its the first time I come across this and am not quite sure of how I am supposed to interpret this. 
Later on in the book it is denoted by:

$\sum_A P(A,C) = P(B)$

but I still have to admit I don't get how to think of it intuitively. 
Furthermore in the book A is a single event and C is a joint event (including A). 
And B is a joint event excluding A. So basically, how does summing over my joint probability with respect to A remove the A?

I know that the following equality exists:

$P_{XY}(x,y) = \sum_Y P_{Y|X}(x,y) P_X(x) = P_X(x)$

and assume tht the above comes from here just with the difference that we only have the joint probability with respect to A, but what does that mean? It still doesn't make sense to me? And why does the book state marginal probability when it actually is denoted by a joint one?